2.4.7-p1 Override product custom options
I am using a custom module which create some new features for magento 2 product custom options. It was working fine till version 2.4.6
Now I am testing version 2.4.7 and it seems that it cannot override magento native custom options. Probably class backwards incompatibility.
Module is enabled in admin but when you edit a product you still see native custom options. It is like module not enabled in this section or in frontend
My module.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <module name="MyModule_DynamicProductOptions" setup_version="2.9.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
            <module name="Magento_Config" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

My di.xml file:
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Options" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Simple" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Virtual" />
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Bundle" />

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Validator\DefaultValidator" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Validator\DefaultValidator" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Value" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Date" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Type\Date" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\DefaultType" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Type\DefaultType" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\File" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Type\File" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Select" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Type\Select" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Text" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Option\Type\Text" />

<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Configurable" />


<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Option" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Option" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Option\Value" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Option\Value" />

<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Bundle\Product\Price" />

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Repository" type="Itoris\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Rewrite\Product\Option\Repository" />

<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
    <plugin name="dpo-quote-item-option-qty" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Plugin\QuoteItemOptionQty"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer">
    <plugin name="dpo-cart-item-option-image" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Plugin\CartItemOptionImage"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder">
    <plugin name="dpo-email-order-item-option-image" type="MyModule\DynamicProductOptions\Plugin\EmailOrderItemOptionImage"/>
</type>

Is it something changed in Magento_Catalog or Magento_Config which breaks my module please?
Any help much appreciated because I am not the developer of that module
